# List all users via Github Graphql v4 API

Tags: github, graphql

Trying to find documentation or figure out how to replicate GitHub's v3 API [Get all users](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users) endpoint via there v4 graphql API.

It's easy enough to query just about anything for a specific user but how can I retrieve a payload listing all users similarly to the v3 API payload?

Can someone point me to the correct documentation or even better provide an example that returns a list of users?

Answer (score 8):

As far as I can tell there is no equivalent to "Get all users" in the v4 api, however, there is a hacky way that you can get close to it using a nodes query.

First you need to be able to generate node ID's to iterate over. Looking at `mojombo` (the first user by database ID) you can see how node ID's are derived.

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/users/mojombo
{
  "login": "mojombo",
  "id": 1,
  "node_id": "MDQ6VXNlcjE=",
  ...
}
$ echo -n "MDQ6VXNlcjE=" | base64 -d
04:User1
```

It is the string `04:User` followed by the users `id` (database ID).

Knowing this we can now generate a nodes query for 100 users at a time. NOTE: Not all database ID's are users, some are organisations or deleted users, and as such you *will* get a lot of `NOT_FOUND` errors.

```
query($ids:[ID!]!) {
    nodes(ids:$ids) {
        ... on User {
            login
        }
    }
}

variables {
    "ids": ["MDQ6VXNlcjE=", "MDQ6VXNlcjI=", ...]
}
```

If you aren't limited to only using the v4 api but still want to take advantage of improved performance of the v4 api then there is a *slightly* less hacky alternative, which is to use the v3 api to get users 100 at a time then use the returned `node_id` field to perform a bulk v4 query across all 100 users using the above technique. Using this method gives far fewer `NOT_FOUND` errors and hence better utilises your rate limit.

To give an idea of the performance improvement you can get using the v4 api and this technique, the task I was performing went from taking an estimated ~474 days using the v3 api to less than 5 days to using this method.

Answer (score 3):

The search query works well for this. You can query based on specific fields, and it will return a list of users. This is usually good if you are looking for one specific user. If you are looking for a large list of users, the search api isn't what you want, since it is optimized for finding one value based on inputs. See an example below:

```
{
  search(query: "location:toronto language:Go", type: USER, first: 10) {
    userCount
    edges {
      node {
        ... on User {
          login
          name
          location
          email
          company
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. Thanks